# Width doesn't work with rotation in iE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, rotation, width

I have some table, which looks like this (in Chrome, Opera, FF):

[image]

But IE (7,8,9) browser displays this table like this:
[image: IE browser]

**Question: how to adjust column width?**

I have two css classes:
for  td tag:

```
.td__vertical{
         text-align:center;
         vertical-align:bottom;
         border:  1px double  #8EB340 ;
         font-size:11px; 
         color:#666; 
         background-color: #F0F4E7; 
         padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
         margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
         width:30px;
}
```

and for div, located inside td tag:

```
.rotated{
        transform: rotate(-90deg); 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
        -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -o-transform-origin:      0 0;
        -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        white-space: nowrap; 
        width: 30px;
}
```

so column described like this:

```
<td class="td__vertical"><div class="rotated" >Column2 Column2 Col..</div></td>
```

Chrome, Opera, FF react on "width: 30px;" in "rotated" class and "width" in "td__vertical" does not matter. But IE not used any of them.
Rotation through the "matrix" has the same effect.

**UPD:** I explored that the column width is the width of the text, that is, the width of the text in the unrotated state. So, how can I switch off auto adjust width of column?

Comment: iam sure that you have used proper doctype

Comment: I'm using <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

Comment: When I set doctype, ie cut my text (by length) in column for 30px! Other browsers - does not.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> - the same effect

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care that in IE the text reads from top to bottom then you can use writing mode:

`-ms-writing-mode: tb-lr;`

This is the equivalent of rotating `90degs`, it's not possible to emulate `-90degs`

Of course, you'd need to remove `filter: progid` and `ms-transform`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531187(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks. It did not help. I remove "filter: progid" and "ms-transform", write "-ms-writing-mode: tb-lr", but ie does not react and display text horizontally